# Website .htaccess file for Wordpress sub folder

Tags: htaccess, wordpress

I developed a Flash website for a client and added the following .htaccess file in the root directory and the non-www to www redirect works perfectly.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I was also asked to add a Wordpress blog so I put it in a new directory folder (as opposed to a sub domain) with so the URL is www.website.com/blog

Does Google now see the main site and blog as two different websites? Do I need to link them together using another .htaccess file in the Wordpress Root so Google automatically crawls the whole domain? Any help appreciated....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will not be seen as two separate websites. They will be seen as one. If you want them to be seen as two separate websites you'll need to put them on two different domains.

You don't have to do anything special for Google to find them as they will follow links to your main site and blog and then crawl them and index them from there. However, you can help the search engines along by using an [XML sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/) to tell them where your pages are.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The main website is Flash so there is no html 'active link' to the blog page. Will Google still be able to find it even with the XML Sitemap?

Comment: If the website is in Flash then the XML sitemap is even more important as, even though Google can index some Flash content, it is generally not considered SEO friendly and links to your blog may not be found. The XML sitemap explicitly tells search engines where your blog is so you know they will find it.